# Additional Emulator Command Line Options doesnt appear to be on my Eclipse

Tags: android

Hi I dont have Additional Emulator Command Line Options textbox on my Eclipse and I have to give some parameters from that textbox but it is not there on Run Configuration ->Target is there any other way how can i give those parameters?

Thanx,

I know this is the second similiar post of me, but i thought the previous post i made no one is looking at in.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just hidden because your window is too small? There is an outer scroll bar on the very right - try dragging it down, then the  text box should appear below disable boot animation

Comment: haha, awesomeeee, thats the problem lol, write this as a accepted answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it's not just hidden because your window is too small? There is an outer scroll bar on the very right - try dragging it down, then the text box should appear below disable boot animation