# Why Uploading project.apk onto device emulator takes so long?

Tags: eclipse, performance, testing, android-emulator, launch

Every time I run a project from ADT to test on a virtual Android device it takes 90+ seconds to upload and another 15+ seconds to "install" it on the device.

Why does it take so long?

Any timeouts I should watch out for? (The eclipse console stays silent.)

Note: project.apk size is about 5MB and computing resources on the development machine are plentiful (i.e. CPU usage is around 5-10%, disk queue length about 0.05 and couple gigs of free RAM available during the "upload" and "install").

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution, but a workaround was found in a similar question:

[Slow uploads to running Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597309/slow-uploads-to-running-android-emulator)

It appears, when the Android emulator is idle its network connection is capped at **2 Mbps**
and when you wake it by clicking and swiping around the bandwidth magically increases to around **10 Mbps**! (At least so on my fairly modern system.)

This obviously makes a difference for uploading largish apps to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Go to Run -> Run Configurations... -> Target Tab -> Additional Emulator Command Line Options. Add there:

```
-netspeed full -netdelay none
```

After doing this the time for uploading went from 2 minutes to 8 seconds.

---

**Edit:**
I have also found that quitting Skype makes my emulator upload much faster.